# Зачем библиотеки обертывают в (function() {...})()?

Tags: javascript, библиотеки, синтаксис

Зачем библиотеки обертывают в (function() {...})()?
Объясните простыми словами, сколько ни читаю - ничего не понятно.

Comment: Чтобы изолировать внутренние переменные

Answer (score 2):

Что бы иметь внутри локальные переменные, недоступные извне:

Например, в примере ниже

```
var libraryCache = {};

library.method1 = function () {
   libraryCache.data = {};
};

library.method2 = function () {
   libraryCache.data2 = {};
};
```

libraryCache доступна любому коду извне, так как она добавляется в глобальный скоп. Если написать так:

```
(function () {
    var libraryCache = {};

    library.method1 = function () {
       libraryCache.data = {};
    };

    library.method2 = function () {
        libraryCache.data2 = {};
    };
})();
```

То мы "скроем" переменную от внешнего кода.

Comment: А-а-а, я, кажется, неправильно понял вопрос.

Comment: А значеине return будет видно?

Comment: @brachkoff Вы имеете ввиду, если будет `(function () { ...; return x; })();`

Comment: Если функция закрытая в этой конструкции будет иметь return

Comment: Если вовращаемое значение куда-то присвоят, тогда можно будет использовать: `var x = (function () { ... })();`, но если нет, тогда никак.

Answer (score 1):

```js
(function() {
 console.log("test");
})();
```

```js
function() {
 console.log("test");
}();
```